# hidden input does not stay hidden when applying css class

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two buttons, one for editing a post, the other for cancel the edit. 
one is supposed to be hidden depending on the edit state. but the cancel button should by default be hidden when the page loads. this worked perfectly until I applied a css class to the buttons.

```
<input onclick="javascript: EditDay();" type="button" value="Edit Day" id="editDayButton" name="editDayButton" class="btn btn-primary" />
<input onclick="javascript: CancelEditDay();" type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancelEditDayButton" name="cancelEditDayButton" hidden="hidden" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

I could probably hide the button with a javascript that runs when the page is loaded. but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Show your css classes please

Comment: `<input hidden="hidden">` that's not work as this. `<input type="hidden">` but will be not a button.

Comment: whats ur css like?

Comment: the css classes I'm using here are standard bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.hidden {
  display: none ;
 }
```

add this to Your CSS file and change your class as

```
 class="btn btn-primary hidden"
```

and make sure your class does not contain any block annotation in the defintion

Edited:
do the following

```
<input onclick="javascript: CancelEditDay();" type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancelEditDayButton" name="cancelEditDayButton" class="btn btn-primary hello hidden"/>
```

and the jquery will be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click','.hello',function(e){
      $('.hello').removeClass('hidden');
   });
});
```

Comment: this hid the button alright, but the javascript that shows the button no longer shows it.$("#editDayButton").hide();
    $("#cancelEditDayButton").show();

Comment: '`$('.yourtagclass').removeClass('hidden');` will do the trick cause the above one you mentioned will remove the attribute but what we defined is a class in the css @inifus

Answer (score 0):

If it was working before you added classes probably bootstrap classes you added contains something like display:inline-block which overrides your previous behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Author CSS has precedence over browser CSS that gives elements with `hidden` attribute the `display: none` style. That is why any display declaration in your css (e.g. `display: inline-block` for Bootstrap buttons) overrides it. You should add an explicit rule like `[hidden] { display:none !important }` to your CSS.

By the way, you don't need `javascript:` prefix for your event listeners. It's needed only for javascript links, e.g. bookmarklets.

Comment: I tried without the javascript: prefix but the javascript functions will not run without it.

Comment: Didn't see any case where `javasript:` prefix (which is technically a JavaScript label in this case) had any effect in `onclick` handler. Are you sure you don't confuse it with `<a href="javascript:...">`?

Comment: My javascript functions were not called when I clicked the button, I asked here for a solution, someone recommended adding the prefix and suddenly the functions worked. I'm new to javascript and mvc so I'm not sure what's going on under the hood most of the time. at the moment it works like this

Comment: Can you please show the simplified example of this behavior? I tend to think that it was just a coincidence, but it's really interesting if it wasn't.

Comment: I don't know what happens in the browser when I click the button with just the handler name in the onclick parameter. but the handler is never called, so it never reaches my breakpoint in the debugger, when I added the javascript: [handlername]() it just worked. I didn't bother to look further into it.